# How to unregister deleted DLL?

Tags: dll, registry, regsvr32

How should a `DLL` be unregistered if it has been deleted?

`regsvr32 /u <filename>` requires the `DLL` to exist.  What if is has been deleted already?

What is the best way to remove the registry entries in this situation?

Comment: Restore it from the recycle bin and then remove it? Unless you have enough information to track down the details in the registry and remove them manually (the COM classes registered, etc.) you're probably out of luck.

Comment: What if the recycle bin doesn't contain the DLL anymore?

Comment: Read the rest of what I wrote - you apparently stopped after the first sentence. :-) Do you have the information you'll need to remove it manually from the registry (a GUID, or a COM class name it registered, at least)?